# Java SOAP request string in POST data

Tags: java, post, soap

I am not familiar with SOAP requests so I have been reading up on it. The examples and tutorials I've looked at construct the request in an xml format in the SOAP envelope.

example:

```
private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

    /*
    Constructed SOAP Request Message:
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <example:VerifyEmail>
                <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
                <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
            </example:VerifyEmail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
     */

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "VerifyEmail");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return soapMessage;
}
```

but the example request that was given to me by the organization with the server is a single line with the request in the URL:

```
http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83Geographic.wfs?Service=WFS&Version=1.0.0&Request=GetFeature&OutputFormat=GML3&TypeName=MapunitPoly&FILTER=<Filter><Intersect><PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>-95.1852448111,43.0186163988 -95.1853350008,43.0183961223 -95.1854898978,43.0183055981 -95.1858276893,43.0182603358 -95.1861146851,43.0183087828 -95.1862558373,43.0184050072 -95.186496397,43.0188380162 -95.1867287441,43.018969948 -95.1871860608,43.0190950058 -95.1872413814,43.0192924831 -95.1869109659,43.0195048805 -95.1863026073,43.019660449 -95.1860721056,43.0196581015 -95.185922908,43.0195072276 -95.1857936581,43.0191228335 -95.1853686954,43.0188252761 -95.1852448111,43.0186163988 -95.1852448111,43.0186163988</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></Intersect></Filter>
```

Here it is again but wrapped and indented for easier reading:

```
http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83Geographic.wfs?
    Service=WFS&
    Version=1.0.0&
    Request=GetFeature&
    OutputFormat=GML3&
    TypeName=MapunitPoly&
    FILTER=<Filter>
        <Intersect>
            <PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName>
            <gml:Polygon>
                <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                    <gml:LinearRing>
                        <gml:coordinates>
                            -95.1852448111,43.0186163988 
                            -95.1853350008,43.0183961223 
                            -95.1854898978,43.0183055981 
                            -95.1858276893,43.0182603358 
                            -95.1861146851,43.0183087828 
                            -95.1862558373,43.0184050072 
                            -95.186496397,43.0188380162 
                            -95.1867287441,43.018969948 
                            -95.1871860608,43.0190950058 
                            -95.1872413814,43.0192924831 
                            -95.1869109659,43.0195048805 
                            -95.1863026073,43.019660449 
                            -95.1860721056,43.0196581015 
                            -95.185922908,43.0195072276 
                            -95.1857936581,43.0191228335 
                            -95.1853686954,43.0188252761 
                            -95.1852448111,43.0186163988 
                            -95.1852448111,43.0186163988
                        </gml:coordinates>
                    </gml:LinearRing>
                </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
            </gml:Polygon>
        </Intersect>
    </Filter>
```

I'm not sure how to either modify this to handle the single line request or to modify the request to fit into this system. Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not SOAP. That's a simple GET request, in which one parameter is an XML document. As such, you can simply issue a GET request using [Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or similar.

Note that if you take the above URL and request it via your browser (a GET) you'll get an XML response back (which you'll need to parse appropriately)

Comment: That makes sense. The organization told me it was a soap request. Being unfamiliar with SOAP, I took their word for it, but things weren't adding up.